# Realm delay at end of write function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I've built a sports game in Xcode/Swift using Realm as a base. It's running and working, but realm transactions are getting slower and slower over time, to the point where it's significantly slower than i'd hope. This is particularly evident in this example.

Each week there are a number of matches, with each player having a GameStat object created for every match (about 2,000 new GameStats created each week).

```
class GameStat: Object {         
  @objc dynamic var iden = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var playerIden = "" // Links to iden of a Player Object
  @objc dynamic var statOne = 0
  @objc dynamic var statTwo = 0
  @objc dynamic var statThree = 0
  etc...

  // Primary Key
  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "iden"
  }
}
```

To prevent multiple realm writes throughout each game, I create GameStats outside of Realm (store in thisGameGameStats array) and then batch write these GameStats to realm once the game is complete. It is this batch write to Realm which is very slow.

```
try! realm.write {
  for gmStat in thisGameGameStats {
    realm.add(gmStat)
  }
}
```

I've measured time taken and I always see the 'for' loop complete after 0.05 seconds. In the first couple of loops, there is no delay for the realm.write function to complete, however after a couple of seasons (c70k records in database) it takes a further 0.50 seconds for the realm.write function to complete.

Is this to be expected, or is there an opportunity to optimise here?

EDIT: By removing the primaryKey, the write becomes significantly quicker and doesn't seem to slow down as the database grows. I'm assuming there is therefore some form of sort by primaryKey that happens on commit.

Comment: There's really not enough info or code to answer. Is this a single user game stored on a single device? Also, I don't see you using an autorelease pool - see [Threading](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#threading). Note that *Realm can be very efficient when writing large amounts of data by batching together multiple mutations within a single transaction* see the example [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#nested-objects)

Comment: Thanks for response Jay. Yep, it's a single user offline game. Added in autoreleasepool and it has improved memory usage (not constantly rising until for loop finishes now), but still seeing 'commit' taking 0.5 seconds. I'm relatively new to Realm, but thought my approach above was classed as a batch transaction as forloop within write. Is there a better way to batch?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly an answer but may provide some validatation and illustrate an interesting point.

**TL;DR**

Writing chunks of objects over time does not have a significant impact on write times - you should not be seeing a significant increase in write times based on the existing volume of data in this use case.

**The long version with setup and testing:**

When a write has completed, realm will generate a notification so we're using that notification to 'time' the writes.

We start with a class var to store the start time of each write and a notification to track when it's done

```
var startTime = Date()
var gameStatNotificationToken: NotificationToken?
```

then we add an observer to realm that will execute when the write has completed that determines the elapsed time between the start time and now

```
func addObserver {
    if let realm = gGetRealm() { //this just gets a realm
        self.gameStatNotificationToken = realm.observe { notification, realm in
            let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(self.startTime)
            print("\(elapsed)")
        }
    }
}
```

Then the code to actually write the data

```
func writeLotsOfData() {
    autoreleasepool {

        var  gameStatArray = [GameStat]()

        for index in 0..<10000 {
            let stat = GameStat()
            stat.playerIden = "\(index)"
            gameStatArray.append(stat)
        }

    
        if let realm = gGetRealm() {
            self.startTime = Date()
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(gameStatArray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then a loop that calls the above code 10 times; writing 10k per loop, 100k total objects.

```
func looper() {
    for i in 0..<10 {
        self.writeLotsOfData()
    }
}
```

So the end result shows no increase in writing over time

```
0.19487500190734863
0.1404169797897339
0.14565002918243408
0.15493690967559814
0.14426898956298828
0.15933406352996826
0.15379595756530762
0.16700804233551025
0.1598280668258667
0.15421009063720703
```

EDIT

Here's the GameStat object I am using - it's identical to the one in the question

```
class GameStat: Object {
  @objc dynamic var iden = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var playerIden = "" // Links to iden of a Player Object
  @objc dynamic var statOne = 0
  @objc dynamic var statTwo = 0
  @objc dynamic var statThree = 0

  // Primary Key
  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "iden"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Jay. A couple of things to follow up on if that’s ok. When i move the timer outside the write loop, that's when i'm seeing the delay. i.e. the action of adding within the write function is quick, but exiting the write loop is what is taking the time.
Time taken to add 1,000 GameStats = 0.1110778 (measured within realm.write)
Stats Ran - 2.655491947

Comment: For some reason, I can't edit my comment above. The end should say... time taken to add 1,000 stats = 0.110778, but time then taken after final add to exit the write function = 2.655491947

Comment: Some more investigating today. By removing the primaryKey, the write becomes significantly quicker and doesn't seem to slow down as the database grows. I'm assuming there is therefore some form of sort by primaryKey that happens on commit.

Comment: @hyperpringle I was giving this some thought and my first answer made a couple of incorrect assumptions about writes. I deleted it and re-did the testing using a more accurate measure of time elapsed. Based on the updating testing, you should not be seeing any kind of significant increase in write times based on the amount of data - I think my testing validates that. Take a look at my do-over answer. Also, realm objects are essentially unordered, except in the case of a List so there is no sort by going on. By the way, super great question so +1 for that.

Comment: thanks again for taking the time to consider this. Am I correct in saying you’re using Int as String as the primaryKey? If you still have the code, can you try setting this as UUID().uuidString please? That is what I’m using and I’d read elsewhere that it might be the culprit (hence me removing in my last comment and it seemingly improving things)

Comment: I stepped away from this but still feel a need to tackle it as it’s really impacting speed of gameplay. I have a lead theory that as you’re not seeing the same, it might be something else in the background slowing things down. These writes are occurring on a screen after navigating through a few other screens. Is it likely to be updating other screens in the background? And if so, is there a way to test/prevent this?

Comment: @hyperpringle I too am interested in the issue. However, the code in my answer holds true and as you can see, writing 100,000 objects is not really causing any kind of delays. That being said, there are other things that can affect those results; SSD vs Hard Drive, other processes running etc. Also, my code was on the main thread and running on a background thread would be better as to not affect the UI. We have unknowns as we don't know what *These writes are occurring on a screen* and *likely to be updating other screens* means. Perhaps you can clarify the question with further details?

Comment: A simplified path to this function is...
> Load Game (this sets the Realm and segues to a tab bar controller)
> Segues to first tab, and enters navigation controller for tab (Gameweek screen)
> Gameweek screen (made up of labels+tables based on Realm objects+Lists)
> Click 'sim games' which segues to a list of games
> Start timer and function which simulates each match and writes stats to Realm (as example).

Question whether the delay at the end of write function may be caused by updating objects in views lower in view hierachy, within nav controller.

Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: @hyperpringle It makes since but your view hierarchy is unrelated to Realm. That being said, we don't know how you're accessing realm in each controller - be it a singleton or a class function or a number of other ways. That could have an affect but we would need to understand what that interaction is within each viewController. Are you casing realm objects to an array anywhere? Do you have filters? How about indexing objects?

Comment: Forgive my lack of technical language - I don't really understand your questions - sorry! In simple terms, say I have a ViewController A with a filtered List from my Realm. I then segue onto a new ViewController B (without 'popping' ViewController A, i.e. it is still there to unwind to...and I therefore the hypothesise the filtered List is still 'live'). I then write to Realm in my new ViewController B. Does the existence of the previous ViewController A and List slow down the write, as it is also updating this filtered List? Or does it not impact as ViewController A is not on top?

Comment: @hyperpringle The existence of controller A with a Realm List object will have no impact on the app or what's happening in controller B. Realm Results objects are  Live Updating so if it's that type of collection, it could be updated by what's written by B. If it's a List object then probably not but again, there are a lot of options and ways to make that happen if you wanted it to. (KVO for example). I think you should post a question about your use case so we can see what your objects look like and any surrounding code - that would help us to provide a more complete answer.

Comment: I've just posted a new question, in simplified form, which I hope helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734436/realm-delay-at-end-of-write-function-could-this-be-caused-by-results-list-updat

Comment: i continue to explore this, and the delay at the end of a write transaction remains and grows as the database increases. Occurs when writing a large (1500) number of objects in a single write transaction. Interestingly same is happening when adding/updating different Object Classes. I'm struggling to find documentation which confirms what happens on commit, but if there is a general 'refresh' of the entire database, I wonder if there is something in my structure slowing things down. i.e. Relationships, indexed properties etc? Are you able to point me somewhere that outlines this?

Comment: Closing this question as better question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67112406/realm-write-commit-time-increasing-dramatically-with-listobject