# mutex lock failed: Invalid argument from autoreleasepool

Tags: swift, realm

I have all methods using `autoreleasepool` to prevent memory leak from `realm` database.
And there's a background thread looper which may be doing some realm operations.
So the `autoreleasepool` is necessary.
All these methods are designed as Singleton pattern.
The following method is one of them.

```
 func deleteMyArticle(by owner: String) throws {
        try autoreleasepool {
            let logHelper = LogHelper(subsystem: "ArticleLogService", category: "deleteMyArticle")

            let realm = try Realm()
            let results = ArticleLogService.shared.getMyArticleLogs(realm, by: owner, distinct: false)
                try realm.write {
                    realm.delete(results)
                }

        }
    }
```

But it throws this exception more than 300 times a week and it may freezes my app randomly which I can't reproduce on my test device.

```
Fatal Exception: std::__1::system_error
mutex lock failed: Invalid argument
Fatal Exception: std::__1::system_error

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.ios.exception
0x0000000000000000
Crashed: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x104b5c7c0 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 180
1  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x104b5cba4 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1176
2  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x104b54174 FIRCLSHandler + 48
3  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x104b4fb34 __FIRCLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 92
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x18f2c2280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x18f271b8c _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
6  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x104b4f2cc FIRCLSExceptionRecord + 212
7  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x104b4ef6c FIRCLSTerminateHandler() + 592
8  libc++abi.dylib                0x1a3aee154 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x1a3aee0ec std::terminate() + 44
10 Realm                          0x105672190 __clang_call_terminate + 10
11 Realm                          0x105a199f0 realm::Group::detach() + 118
12 Realm                          0x105a236c4 realm::Transaction::close() + 60
13 Realm                          0x105a26350 TransactionDeleter(realm::Transaction*) + 20
14 Realm                          0x105a2b360 std::__1::__shared_ptr_pointer<realm::Transaction*, void (*)(realm::Transaction*), std::__1::allocator<realm::Transaction> >::__on_zero_shared() + 20
15 Realm                          0x105674da0 std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::app::App>::~shared_ptr() + 64
16 Realm                          0x1057d6980 realm::Realm::~Realm() + 96
17 Realm                          0x105674da0 std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::app::App>::~shared_ptr() + 64
18 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a39f1ae0 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 112
19 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a3a078a4 objc_destructInstance + 88
20 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a3a0e6ec _objc_rootDealloc + 52
21 Realm                          0x1057b58b0 -[RLMRealm dealloc] + 92
22 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a3a11574 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 200
23 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a3a11450 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 208
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f2c2260 _dispatch_last_resort_autorelease_pool_pop + 40
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f26b908 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 520
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f275338 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 712
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d7dbf5a4 _pthread_wqthread + 272
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d7dc2874 start_wqthread + 8
```

Is there any issue if I'm using `autoreleasepool` on the main thread?
According to firebase, the app state are 100% in the background state when these issues occured.
What's the cause of this issue?

RealmSwift 10.1.4
XCode 12.4
iOS 10-14

**UPDATE**

There is a `realm.invalidate()` in `AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate`.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    RealmCacheHelper.shared.invalidateSemaphore.wait()
    defer {
        RealmCacheHelper.shared.invalidateSemaphore.signal()
    }

    if let realm = try? Realm() {
        realm.invalidate()
    }
}
```

And an insert operation(worker thread) of realm in `AppDelegate.applicationDidEnterBackground` to save caches which are loaded from web services.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // insert(caches:);
}

public func insert(caches c: [String:[MemoryCache]]?){
    transactionQueue.async {
        do {
            RealmCacheHelper.shared.invalidateSemaphore.wait()

            let logHelper = LogHelper(subsystem: "PageCacheService", category: "insertCache")

            var backgroundTaskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?

            // Request the task assertion and save the ID.
            backgroundTaskID = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask (withName: "PageCache insertion task.") {
                logHelper.w("Background task expired.")
                // End the task if time expires.
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskID!)
                backgroundTaskID = .invalid
            }

            defer{
                RealmCacheHelper.shared.invalidateSemaphore.signal()
                logHelper.i("Background task finished.")
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskID!)
                backgroundTaskID = .invalid
            }

            // realm.write()
        }
        catch{}
    }
}
```

All of these are used to prevent the size of realm increases drastically. The reason to save caches in `applicationDidEnterBackground` is to decrease the operation frequency of realm.
There was a `autoreleasepool` in the `transactionQueue`. But it crashed a lot too, so I removed it few weeks ago.
I think these `realm` operations in the background state may be the cause of `mutex lock failed` issue. But I have to do these task in the background state.
There may be 50 or more json strings to be saved.

**UPDATE**

@Jay I have everything you need in my code, I just discarded these things to make it looks more easier to read. The try-catch is in the `//realm.write` comment. And it didn't catch any error because the problem was not thrown by this method. `RealmCacheHelper` is a singleton object which holds the same `invalidateSemaphore` to make sure there's nothing running in the background when it's calling `realm.invalidate()`.
Most of your concerns are not related to this issue. That's why I removed them from the code snippet.

This is the nil checker.

```
   guard let caches = c, !caches.isEmpty else {
        let logHelper = LogHelper(subsystem: "PageCacheService", category: "insertCache")
        logHelper.i("Memory cache is empty.")
        return
    }
```

This is why I need try-catch.

```
    let _realm = try RealmCacheHelper.shared.realm()

    _realm.beginWrite()

    for memoryCache in memoryCaches {
        let mid = PageCacheService.shared.getWorkerThreadMID(_realm)

        let cache = MatrixCache.newInstance(
                id: mid,
                controllerId: memoryCache.controllerId,
                page: memoryCache.page)

        cache.content = memoryCache.matrixJson
        cache.font = memoryCache.fontJson

        _realm.add(cache)
    }

    try _realm.commitWrite()
```

```
    func getWorkerThreadMID(_ realm: Realm) -> Int {
        semaphore.wait()
        defer {
            semaphore.signal()
        }

        _mid = autoIncrement(
                realm: realm,
                id: _mid,
                realmObject: MATRIX_CLASS,
                primaryKey: MatrixCache.Column.PrimaryKey.rawValue
        )

        return _mid;
    }
```

```
    internal func autoIncrement(realm: Realm, id: Int, realmObject: Object.Type, primaryKey: String) -> Int{
        if( id == -1 ){
            return ( realm.objects( realmObject ).max(ofProperty: primaryKey) as Int? ?? 0 ) + 1
        }
        
        return id + 1
    }
```

```
    // RealmCacheHelper.shared.realm()
    func realm() throws -> Realm {
        return try Realm(configuration: config)
    }

    var config: Realm.Configuration {

        var _config = Realm.Configuration(
                // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
                // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
                schemaVersion: RealmCacheHelper.schemaVersion,
                // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
                // a schema version lower than the one set above
                migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                    // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
                    if (oldSchemaVersion < RealmCacheHelper.schemaVersion) {
                        // Nothing to do!
                        // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
                        // And will update the schema on disk automatically
                    }
                },
                deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
        )

        // let it crash if the fileURL is nil.
        _config.fileURL = _config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent(RealmCacheHelper.realmFileName)

        #if DEBUG
        _config.maximumNumberOfActiveVersions = 5
        #endif

        return _config
    }
```

And `LogHelper` is just a convenient class to use `CocoaLumberjack`.
v for verbose, i for info, w for warn, d for debug, e for error.

```
    let headerV: String
    let headerD: String
    let headerI: String
    let headerW: String
    let headerE: String

    init(subsystem: String, category: String){
        headerV = "[" + subsystem + "/" + category + "] [VERBOSE] "
        headerD = "[" + subsystem + "/" + category + "] [DEBUG] "
        headerI = "[" + subsystem + "/" + category + "] [INFO] "
        headerW = "[" + subsystem + "/" + category + "] [WARN] "
        headerE = "[" + subsystem + "/" + category + "] [ERROR] "
    }

    public func v(_ message: String){
        DDLogVerbose(headerV + message)
    }
```

```
    // ArticleLogService.shared.getMyArticleLogs(realm, by: owner, distinct: false)
    func getMyArticleLogs(_ realm: Realm, by owner: String, distinct: Bool) -> Results<ArticleLog> {
        if distinct {
            return realm.objects(ENTITY_CLASS).filter("\(ArticleLog.Column.Owner.rawValue) = '\(owner)' AND \(ArticleLog.Column.Author.rawValue) contains[cd] %@", owner).sorted(byKeyPath: ArticleLog.Column.CreatedDate.rawValue, ascending: false).distinct(by: [ArticleLog.Column.BoardTitle.rawValue, ArticleLog.Column.Aid.rawValue])
        }
        else {
            return realm.objects(ENTITY_CLASS).filter("\(ArticleLog.Column.Owner.rawValue) = '\(owner)' AND \(ArticleLog.Column.Author.rawValue) contains[cd] %@", owner).sorted(byKeyPath: ArticleLog.Column.CreatedDate.rawValue, ascending: false)
        }
    }
```

It do throw `mutex lock failed` randomly only if I add `autoreleasepool` in the `insert` method.
So there must be something wrong here while running this method in the background state.
But everything is the same as other methods running on the main thread.

Comment: It seems to me that a destructor in Realm is throwing an exception (which leads to termination of your app). You're probably misusing one of their API’s.

Comment: @idmean I just updated my question. Is there anything unusual?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Realm. I was only glimpsing over the stack trace. But it might be as you can see `RLMRealm` high up in the trace.

Comment: There is no way we will be able to assist with this as there is too much additional code that could be causing the issue - and it's not included in the question; We don't know what `LogHelper`, `ArticleLogService`, `RealmCacheHelper` are. There are also a number of optionals that are force-unwrapped `backgroundTaskID!` or that don't have nil situations handled `[String:[MemoryCache]]?` that could be nil but you won't know about it. There are also several places with error checking is being overridden `catch{}`, `let realm = try Realm()`, which could reveal issues. Add err checking!

Comment: @Jay I just added everything you need in my question.

Comment: There's way too much code to process through. That being said, my (total) guess based the code and crash log is that you're attempting to delete objects on a different thread than they were created on.

Comment: One unrelated thing did catch my eye though *There may be 50 or more json strings to be saved*. It seems you have a lot of code to handle that; writing 50 of anything to realm would have very little, if any impact, to the UI so I don't understand the need for all of that extra code. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385760/realm-delay-at-end-of-write-function/65428288?noredirect=1#comment116722104_65428288) where the user is experiencing slow performance and then my answer writing a large number of objects (on the main thread so we can time the writes)

Comment: @Jay Because the json string is not short. As you can see there are two json strings to be saved to `MatrixCache`. The average length of `cache.content` is 7000, another one is 40000. So the total string length to write is about 50000. That's why I use a worker thread to do this job. Is your "delete object" means a `realm` object? Otherwise, I didn't delete any object here or somewhere else. Is `realm.invalidate` a problem? Because the `RLMRealm dealloc` in the error report makes it looks like it was triggered by `realm.invalidate`. And this is the only thing I deleted from memory on purpose.

Comment: Is that 50000 *bytes* as in .05 Mb? Even if it's UTF-8 bytes, that's still a tiny amount of data. *Otherwise, I didn't delete any object here or somewhere else.* -> `realm.delete(results)`? That code deletes one or a bunch of objects and may be in the crash log `TransactionDeleter(realm::Transaction*) + 20`. Again, just guessing.

Comment: @Jay It's a good start to find the cause to me. I just tested to write, find and delete the same data concurrently for 1000 times, but still nothing happened. I think it's because the `RealmCacheHelper.shared.invalidateSemaphore.wait()`.

Comment: @Jay Maybe the `TransactionDeleter` does not relate to `realm.delete()`. Because the error report from the `insert` method in my question throws the same error report, if I wrap it in the `autoreleasepool`. So it may be just a method to end transaction.