# Realm write commit time increasing dramatically with List<Object>

Tags: swift, realm

I've asked a significantly less pointed question previously querying why my app is slowing down significantly (as the database grows) when committing a Write, but I have now reproduced my issue with a simple example.

My app has Players, each with a List of Skills (a new Skill is added each year, to track progress, hence the List).

Minimal example as follows:

```
class PlayerTest: Object {
    @objc dynamic var iden = UUID().uuidString
    let skill = List<SkillTest>() // Edited based on feedback
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "iden"
    }
}

class SkillTest: Object {
    @objc dynamic var iden = UUID().uuidString
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "iden"
    }
}
```

Now if I create a PlayerTest, with an associated SkillTest and add to Realm in batches, I see the time to write increase fairly dramatically as the database grows.
Edit: Updated code per feedback. Reduced some distractions and isolated it to the impact of List (hopefully correctly this time).

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    for _ in 1...100 {
         startTime = Date()
         autoreleasepool {
             try! realm.write {
                  for _ in 1...1000 {
                      let plyrTest = PlayerTest()
                      plyrTest.skill.append(SkillTest())
                      realm.add(plyrTest)
                  }
             }
         }
    let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(self.startTime)
    print("\(elapsed)")
}
```

The time to write increases massively. And looking at specific timings, it's not the 'add' that takes the time, it is whatever happens when committing the block to write.

- The larger the list of Skills, the longer the commit.

Time to 'Pre-Commit' - Stays static over time as database grows. Higher when doing more. Nothing surprising here.
[image]

Time to 'Commit' - Increases dramatically as database grows.
[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a shortcoming of Realm, with increased complexity?

Edit again:
Elapsed output with above code

```
0.08156692981719971
0.07571196556091309
0.07729697227478027
0.07823300361633301
0.07565093040466309
0.07614004611968994
0.08084392547607422
0.07980704307556152
0.07947099208831787
0.09374105930328369
0.08172392845153809
0.08766007423400879
0.12517797946929932
0.08668792247772217
0.09016799926757812
0.09452903270721436
0.08788204193115234
0.09242498874664307
0.10330498218536377
0.09574401378631592
0.0972510576248169
0.10320806503295898
0.09910500049591064
0.1097790002822876
0.11233603954315186
0.10901105403900146
0.10672104358673096
0.10959005355834961
0.10411298274993896
0.11345493793487549
0.12051200866699219
0.10799801349639893
0.11797809600830078
0.14078497886657715
0.11560094356536865
0.1292179822921753
0.13037991523742676
0.16984689235687256
0.13681495189666748
0.1367340087890625
0.13127601146697998
0.1376129388809204
0.14138996601104736
0.14629805088043213
0.15031909942626953
0.13964498043060303
0.14714598655700684
0.15111100673675537
0.14821505546569824
0.14652299880981445
0.18220102787017822
0.19571495056152344
0.22607505321502686
0.2373208999633789
0.2501910924911499
0.2722630500793457
0.34519195556640625
0.400797963142395
0.43305695056915283
0.4490790367126465
0.4825640916824341
0.47102999687194824
0.5166339874267578
0.4920459985733032
0.5681279897689819
0.5091359615325928
0.5372620820999146
0.5162559747695923
0.5743310451507568
0.624782919883728
0.6881899833679199
0.7521489858627319
0.7075200080871582
0.6973060369491577
0.6249380111694336
0.6569089889526367
0.7154569625854492
0.7897250652313232
0.7067869901657104
0.7808139324188232
0.765550971031189
0.7594120502471924
0.8092950582504272
0.7826380729675293
0.8118910789489746
0.8939770460128784
0.9101930856704712
0.906669020652771
1.0064159631729126
1.126439094543457
0.9952520132064819
1.4507620334625244
1.2510830163955688
1.1479289531707764
1.1368379592895508
1.2081060409545898
1.2272610664367676
1.1548240184783936
1.2422831058502197
1.2633819580078125
```

Comment: A couple of high-level things. A [List Object](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/ios-swift/#define-the-object-models) is defined like this `let myList = List<MyObject>()` not `dynamic var skill = List<SkillTest>()`. Second there's an issue in the code unrelated to Realm. When working with large amounts of data, enclosing them in an autorelease pool will ensure they are properly released and don't continue to occupy memory. [Here's a use case example](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/sync-changes-between-devices/#reset-a-client-realm-file)

Comment: The code in your question not only writes to realm, but read it over and over which throws the write times off because you're also reading from an ever expanding list during the process. There's not reason to do that and will obviously cause the times to increase with the more items that are **read**. Once an object is added to Realm and meets the results criteria (like a filtered results) they will automagically be available within results.

Comment: For other users future reference, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385760/realm-delay-at-end-of-write-function/65428288?noredirect=1#comment118627089_65428288) which performs a true write-only test.

Comment: Firstly, thanks again Jay. I apologise if i'm frustrating - still learning! :-)
I've corrected dynamic var -> let as suggested and wrapped in autoreleasepool.
I've also removed reads within the test and become 'write-only', but still observing the same outcome.
Note: The previous test you helped with didn't have the List element, which might be why we couldn't replicate.

Comment: The List won't affect the outcome. There are other code issues which cause the numbers to be inaccurate. Printing to console is an inherently slow process and those print statements are within the loop so they are repeatedly called. We don't know what `DispatchTime.now()` does or why its needed; you should get the start time `var startTime = Date()` and when done, get the end time; the difference is the total time. Do that process 10 times and compare the first time to the last time. (see my prior answer). Also, the code is the question is now stale so you should refresh it with updated code.

Comment: Edited code and hopefully now makes more sense (I haven't used notificationToken as couldn't make that work, but hopefully that doesn't take away from the main problem here). Have added the times observed to the bottom of the question, showing the increase, as per the chart. If I remove `let skill = List<SkillTest>` from PlayerTest then solely add PlayerTest in each loop, then I don't see the increase. List is definitely slowing things.

Comment: Nope. That's still not going to be anywhere near accurate. The autorelease pool is not in correct spot (see the code in my prior example); autorelease each set of data, not the entire set of data. This is also not a pure writing test because this code `for _ in 1...1000 {let randPlyr......` searches 1000 indexes each loop and gobbles up memory as well. What's happening there is the code is writing 1000 objects, then scanning through 1000 objects (loading them into RAM memory) and writing them back out again.

Comment: Keep in mind that Realm objects are lazily loaded and don't take up memory until they are needed. For example; a 10,000 objects in a Results would take up almost no memory. However, as soon as it's cast it to an array or a Swift function is run on it, it loads ALL of that data into memory. So, `randomElement()` is a Swift function; those objects loose their lazy loadingness and take up memory. Therefore slowing down everything due to the number of them hanging out in RAM. So that code has two writes per loop + memory use; doubling the time and making the example inaccurate.

Comment: Updated code in question again and further simplied. Time still increases gradually and then dramatically as database grows. If I comment out `plyrTest.skill.append(SkillTest())`, then the write time does not increase as dramatically. Is this just an expected outcome from such a big database?

Comment: So. I ran that code, it output 100 numbers to my console. The first number was `0.07609307765960693`, the last number was `0.1086430549621582`, a difference of .032s. So would I say that's an increase? Technically yes, but in the big picture when you compare 1000 items in the database and 100,000 items in the database, thats a negligible difference. Keep in mind that your code actually creates TWO objects so the dataset is *double* what I just mentioned.

Comment: I closed this question and pointed it back to the original question as the questions are very similar and it's best to keep all of the data in one place instead of duplicating it. If you have more data *please* update that question which remains open - we will try to help!